# Kotlin: BiFunction with nullable return value fails to compile

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-android

This (greatly simplified) code fails to compile for me. Not sure why. The return type is `Entry?` and `null` seems like a valid value to me.

```
val foo = BiFunction<Int, List<Entry>, Entry?> { foo:Int, bar:List<Entry> ->
    null
}
```

The error message is `Null can not be a value of a non-null type Entry`

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

I am using:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.10'
compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.8"
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
```

I welcome any suggestions. Happy New Year!

Comment: rxjava's BiFunction, not the Java BiFunction.

Comment: Ah, right, ok..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`apply`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/functions/BiFunction.html#apply-T1-T2-) method in the `BiFunction` class has a `@NonNull` annotation on its return value (as well as on its parameters). Apparently you can't override this by providing a nullable type as the type argument.

You probably shouldn't either: RxJava 2 streams can't have `null` elements in them (see [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#nulls)).